# Check if normal vector points up/down or to the side

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to determine whether a cluster of points on a 3D surface is "pointing" either upwards/downwards or to the left/right side.

Right now I'm trying to achieve this by getting the average normal vector of such a cluster of points. So for example I have this (average) normal vector $(-0.46848393, 0.85759859, 0.09872456)$ of which I know it points up. I also have this (average) normal vector $(0.95095073, -0.06399548, -0.20965315)$ of which I know that it points to the left.

I now check if the absolute value of the y-coordinate is higher than the absolute value of the x-coordinate to check if it is pointing upwards, but this gives me results which are not always correct. So I was wondering if anyone would know the correct way to derive the direction using the normal vector.

Comment: Where do $\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},0\right)$ point? )

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: In what direction do vectors $(0.7071067811865476,0.7071067811865476,0)$, $(-0.7071067811865476,0.7071067811865476,0)$, $(0.7071067811865476,-0.7071067811865476,0)$, $(-0.7071067811865476,-0.7071067811865476,0)$ point? In other words, you need maximal absolute value of coordinates of a vector, and if it's $x$, the vector points left or right, or if $y$, the vector points up or down, correct? If it's not always correct, then the direction cannot be decided by the vector alone and thus you need to add more detail to the question...

Answer (score 0):

I can give my suggestion, although seems to me this is a very open ended question needing interpretation.

My understanding is you have a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $n$ points on that surface $p_n = (x_n , y_n , z_n)$.  And for each point you can get a normal vector $\bar{p}_n = (\bar{x}_n , \bar{y}_n , \bar{z}_n)$.  And you want an ``average'' vector that tells you in what direction the normal vectors generally point.

Why not take the componentwise average of the normals?
$$\bar{p}_{average} = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\bar{x}_k}{n} , \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\bar{y}_k}{n} , \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\bar{z}_k}{n} \right) $$

I tried for a couple basic  examples and it matches with my own intuition